# How do I fix the ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer error for discord cog with python?

Tags: python, discord

I get this error for my ping command.

```
await ctx.send(f"Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

The actual ping/latency part does not display itself in Discord when the command is entered. However, if I remove the curly braces part, it displays Pong just fine.

This is my whole code (It is in a cog):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "oof ")

class Other(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    # Events
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Ping is ready.")

    # Commands
    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Other(client))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
@commands.command()
async def ping(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Pong! {round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms")
```